# .NET Core JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>, JsonReaderOptions) failed to parse from WebSocket ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use .NET Core 3.0's `JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>, JsonReaderOptions)` to parse WS message (`byte[]`) to JSON, but it throws an exception as below:

```
'0x00' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 34.
```

This is my Middleware snippet code:

```
WebSocket ws = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4];
ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes);

while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
       try
       {
             WebSocketReceiveResult request = await ws.ReceiveAsync(bytes, CancellationToken.None);
             switch (request.MessageType)
             {
                     case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                             string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                             json = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(bytes);
                             JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
                             break;
                     default:
                             break;
             }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
             Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}\r\n{e.StackTrace}");
       }
 }
```

Comment: Your buffer is bigger then the payload. You should use the new memory api's all the way. Your current code just doesn't take the advantage of the new Span/Memory features (cause you are allocating the buff yourself rather than renting it from the memory pool. You need to slice the `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` to the number of bytes where it actually contains the data

Comment: @tseng I added `json = json.Slice(0, bytes.Length);` before parsing, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: not `bytes.Length`, thats the length of your own buffer. You need to use `request.Count` which will give you the number of bytes read from the socket. Will post proper answer soon

Comment: @tseng It should be `json = json.Slice(0, request.Count);`, right?

Comment: Yes. This may work in many cases, but may fail later on if the message doesn't fit into a single packet. In that case you would need to continue to buffer the input until you have a full payload, but its out of the scope of the current question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you did some mistakes. One of the biggest one is that you allocate the memory (causes allocations and gc in the long run, something Memory/Span API wants to avoid). The second being, you didn't slice your data, since your payload is smaller then the buffer size.

Some fixes I'd did to the code

```
WebSocket ws = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
// Don't do that, it allocates. Beats the main idea of using [ReadOnly]Span/Memory
// byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4];

// We don't need this either, its old API. Websockets support Memory<byte> in an overload
// ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes);

// We ask for a buffer from the pool with a size hint of 4kb. This way we avoid small allocations and releases
// P.S. "using" is new syntax for using(disposable) { } which will
// dispose at the end of the method. new in C# 8.0
using IMemoryOwner<byte> memory = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024 * 4);

while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    try
    {
        ValueWebSocketReceiveResult request = await ws.ReceiveAsync(memory.Memory, CancellationToken.None);
        switch (request.MessageType)
        {
            case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                // we directly work on the rented buffer
                string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.Memory.Span);
                // here we slice the memory. Keep in mind that this **DO NOT ALLOCATE** new memory, it just slice the existing memory
                // reason why it doesnt allocate is, is that Memory<T> is a struct, so its stored on the stack and contains start 
                // and end position of the sliced array
                JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(memory.Memory.Slice(0, request.Count));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}\r\n{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

You need to slice it, so the Json parser won't read beyond the end of the JSON string.

Comment: Would the allocated memory rent from MemoryPool expand automatically if the packet size is greater than 4kb?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan: IIRC from top of my head no (don't quote me on these), but if you want best possible performance you should use the new `System.IO.Pipelines` library and classes. This way you can pump your data as fast as possible into the pipe line and have a reader find out the boundaries and process the messages as they come.This way processing of your message won't "block" your socket reader when it gets data in.Take a look on a [good introduction to pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) from David Fowler on Pipelines can found